# Delete Xcode shared folder

Tags: macos, hard-drive, xcode, disk-space

Can I delete the Developer > Xcode > Shared folder? I want to clear out space and noticed that it takes up 2 gigs of data. Is it safe to delete? I use Xcode often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about ~/Library/Developer/Shared, then this folder contains all the documentation for the OS X and iOS frameworks (if applicable). This folder should not be deleted if you require access to the documentation.

Comment: documentation, as in, guides and info?

Comment: @Demosthenes All the documentation in Documentation & API Reference (open Xcode and press ⇧⌘0). This includes autocomplete for method names in iOS/OS X, etc.